# How do I alter the stroke width along a path/line?

Tags: svg, inkscape

Having read the SVG2 draft, I am slightly disappointed to learn that there will be [no new line caps](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-SVG2-20130409/painting.html#LineCaps) than the standard 3.  The [new arc line join is brilliant however](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-SVG2-20130409/painting.html#LineJoin), but not what this question is about (I just wanted to mention that).

I had been hoping for a cap that ends in a triangle.  But given my use case, that might not be ideal either.

As far as I can gather, Adobe Illustrator - which I do not use myself - allows the width of a stroke to be variable.  This is useful when drawing from a drawing tablet, to highlight the pressure of the lines.  It's true, this functionality exists in many bitmap drawing programs, but is there a way to achieve this effect in SVG, without having to draw multiple lines?

The idea is that each node should have a width, and the lines should then 'smoothly' scale the width between each node that had a different width.

Is this possible?  And if not, could it be considered?

P.S. I should point out, that this is more a thought experiment and an idea than something that hinders my process.  More of a nice to have than need to have.

Comment: Why not send your feedback to w3c svg editors via http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/

Comment: That's not a bad idea.

Comment: Just wanted to report in that this exists now https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/Proposals/Variable_width_stroke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this may not be a true answer (SVG standard wise at least), it turns out that in the current trunk version of Inkscape, this [feature called PowerStroke already exists](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/0.49#PowerStroke).  There are some [screenshots of PowerStroke](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=12230&p=45492#p45492).

This should satisfy my quest for the time being.

It turns out - as well - that the arc line joins was actually [suggested by Inkscape](http://tavmjong.free.fr/blog/?p=646) as well, they are just called extrapolate in Inkscape.